# Is that necessary to unit test code generated by Apache Thrift?

Tags: unit-testing, thrift

We are presenting unit tests for a C++ project. Our goal is to cover up to 60% the whole project. The project uses a lot of code generated by Apache Thrift for communication between Client and Server.

Should we make unit tests for the generated code? If we don't introduce unit tests for the code, some coverage tools will be complaining that we are neglecting a big part of the project.

Does Apache Thrift provide those unit tests already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of tests that run on the CI servers to ensure

- the Thrift compiler can be built and works
- the language bindings can be built and work
- the language bindings operate as expected (including cross-lang tests)

In addition to the [Apache Thrift Test Suite](https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/master/test) each language binding may or may not define additional tests to test specific things as needed, [e.g. as shown here](https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/master/lib/go/test).

Regarding "is it necessary": First, we all make errors ([except Linus](https://twitter.com/codextasy/status/10981315544) of course). I would probably not go as far and test the entire thing again, but I would test those pieces in my own code that implement a certain behaviour using that 3rd party library.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Apache Thrift specifically, but it's probably safe to assume that any "big name" library/framework will have their own tests to try to ensure that it isn't fundamentally broken. However:

- Those tests can't test your use of the library/framework. From a 30-second search, Thrift uses an *Interface Definition Language*, so if there are "problems" in the IDL code you write, Thrift may generate incorrect code (it *may* complain, but think the equivalent of *undefined behaviour* in C/C++).
- Their tests won't test how your code *uses* the automatically generated code. You might be using it in ways it wasn't intended to be used, and so their "correct" code can still give the wrong results (for your application).
- New releases of Thrift may behave differently than earlier versions, in ways that break your use of it. Assuming they're mentioned, scouring Release Notes for such changes is error-prone, so you may want some tests on features you rely on in the rest of your application.  Especially important if you keep more-or-less automatically up-to-date with the latest version.

So, you probably don't need to unit-test it to the degree you would if you had written the code, but you will want tests near the generated code to detect problems with your use of it and/or changes in behaviour as new versions are released.